# google salve - maven

Tags: maven-2

I tried to install google salve http://code.google.com/p/salve/ by adding following statements in the project's pom file:
However, when running mvn dependency:resolve it states "unable to find resource "salve:salve:jar:2.0" in repository salve

What's wrong?

```
  <dependency>
              <groupId>salve</groupId>
              <artifactId>salve</artifactId>
              <version>2.0</version>
          </dependency>

  <repository>
              <id>salve</id>
              <name>Google Maven Repository</name>
              <url>http://salve.googlecode.com/svn/maven2/</url>
  </repository>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `salve` artifact you're mentioning is a `pom` (and indeed, there is no `salve:salve:jar:2.0`). If this is really the dependency you want to declare, you need to specify the `type`:

```
<project>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>salve</id>
      <name>Google Maven Repository</name>
      <url>http://salve.googlecode.com/svn/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>salve</groupId>
      <artifactId>salve</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Honestly, I doubt you want the `pom` but I can't tell you which artifact you need.

**Update:** I guess you would have figured this out yourself but for salve-depend-guice, use the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>salve</groupId>
      <artifactId>salve-depend-guice</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The dependencies of the above artifact will be downloaded transitively by Maven.

Comment: I would need the http://salve.googlecode.com/svn/maven2/salve/salve-depend-guice/2.0/, I hope that it includes all stuff. How do I have to change that the jar files are downloaded ?